# Selenium Wait for anyone of Element to visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

While Clicking a particular button - my test site will open modal window.

But the modal window opens are differ, either it opened with `modal window 1 or modal window 2`

Both are having different title, different options and different locators. 
Now I should have to wait until the modal `window open Either 1 or 2`.

Is it possible to wait until either one modal window (WebElement) is visible?

I have searched in WebDriverWait methods, but all methods are to wait until a particular WebElement to visible or clickable.

I can't find a better method to wait until either one is visible.

Could you suggests any one method to solve this situation?

Comment: Please share Html tag and Code.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="docmnt"]/span[1]/button")).click();
 
WebElement ele2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="updocmnt"]/div/div/div[1]/h4"));
 
WebElement ele3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="complete"]/div/div/div[1]"));

  WebDriverWait wait =new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele2));

but I have to wait until visibility of Either ele2 or ele3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `or` [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#or-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition) for that

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id1")),
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id2"))
));
```

Or use `cssSelector` or `,`

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#id1, #id2"));
```

Comment: when i use that i get the method or is undefined for type ExpectedConditions. any ideas why

Comment: @ShanmukhaBollapragada You should post a new question with the details and the code.

Comment: (By.cssSelector("#id1, #id2")) );  <--- this semi colon is missing :p

Answer (score 0):

To induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) until either one modal window [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is visible you can use the [`or()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#or(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition...)) clause as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("name_modalA_element")),
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_modalB_element"))
));
```

With `cssSelector` you can seperate the elements using the comma character i.e. **`,`** as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("css_modalA_element, css_modalB_element"));
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to extract dynamic text from multiple child nodes within the html through getText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034819/how-to-extract-dynamic-text-from-multiple-child-nodes-within-the-html-through-ge/51035034#51035034)
- [Logic Operators in WebDriverWait Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147145/logic-operators-in-webdriverwait-expected-conditions/46147830#46147830)
- [How to wait for either of the two elements in the page using selenium xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166181/how-to-wait-for-either-of-the-two-elements-in-the-page-using-selenium-xpath/45170764#45170764)