# How to wait for either of the two elements in the page using selenium xpath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have two elements I can wait for, I want to `wait` until either of them appears on the page.

I am trying to use `xpath` locator. But it is not working.

```
By.xpath("//*[(contains(@id,'idNumber1')) or (contains(@id,'idNumber2'))]"));
```

Is this achievable? 
Please help me out.

Comment: not working mean what. getting any error or anything else ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath OR operator for different nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350666/xpath-or-operator-for-different-nodes)

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to wait for one of two elements in the page using `ExpectedConditions.or()`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("idNumber1")),
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("idNumber2"))
));
```

You can also do an `OR` with a CSS selector using a comma `,`:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#idNumber1, #idNumber2"));
```

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for the edit. But I am still wondering about your comment **"Removed references to XPath that didn't exist in code"**. The two code changes you made are: replaced the name of object from `wait9` to `wait` & replaced `wait10` to `wait`. Where is the **references to XPath ?**. Please clarify. Additionally, is a object name as `wait9` &  `wait10` invalid? Please explain. Thanks

Comment: Exactly... there were no XPaths in your code but your descriptions referenced them twice, "It is possible to wait for one of two elements in the page using selenium **xpath**" and, "Using **`xpath`**:". You can see in the edits for yourself.

Comment: `wait9` and `wait10` aren't invalid but what do they mean? What is `wait9` vs `wait10`? How will another user, or yourself in a few months, know what the difference is. In your sample code, the two waits were exactly the same so there's no need to have different variable names. Once `wait` is declared, it can be reused for any other scenario that can use a 10s wait. I think people forget that often because I see it in answers.. I simplified it here as a part of the cleanup/edit.

Comment: @JeffC This was the `xpath` code block where you needlessly converted `wait9` to `wait`: `WebDriverWait wait9 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait9.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("idNumber1")),
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("idNumber2"))
        )); `

Comment: I saw the code before and I can see it now in the edits. You didn't answer my questions. There's no need to slap a 9 on the end of the variable name... where are the other 8? What does the 9 mean? It means nothing in this context so I removed it... which I already explained.

Comment: @JeffC This was the `css` code block where you needlessly removed the line `WebDriverWait wait10 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);`, orphaned the line: `WebDriverWait wait10 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait10.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#idNumber1, #idNumber2"));` and needlessly converted `wait10` to `wait` which looks to me unethical as per stackoverflow standards. Thanks

Comment: Are you going to nitpick every change I made? I already explained why I did it. I removed the second `wait` declaration because it was exactly the same as the first, which is already contained in the first code block, so there is no need to have it twice.

Comment: @JeffC Whats wrong in a object name as `Obj10` or `obj100` or `_time` ?

Comment: I'm not going to keep answering the same question over and over. Read my previous two replies. You need to explain why you need the 9 or 10 appended to the variable here... what purpose does it serve?

Comment: I think you need to understand `Java`, `Python`, etc languages have their own variable naming convention and standards. As far as my code follows them and produces accurate results there shouldn't be any nitpicks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please provide few seconds of `wait` before move to this code, so your driver may able to find the web-element.

Try this `xpath`

```
//*[contains(@id, 'idNumber1') or contains(@id, 'idNumber2')]
```

Comment: Any specific difference  with what OP have ?

Comment: Yes, there is no specific difference between above @karthik and mine `xpath`. But it's makes difference in term of syntax only. for more details on this please refer this link. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

The `xpath` looks valid. Use explicit wait to wait for visibility

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[(contains(@id,'idNumber1')) or (contains(@id,'idNumber2'))]")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Xpath :-

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'idNumber1') or (contains(@id,'idNumber2'))]"))
```

Comment: can you describe the difference between what you have posted and what OP have ?

Comment: there is syntax mistake in give Question which i have rectified in my ans