# Explicit wait for two elements using OR operator in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to find either one of the 2 elements in selenium (java). If anyone is found then that should be clicked. following is not working;

```
WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);                     
wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@data-period='R6M'] || //span[@title='FYTD']"))).click();
```

Comment: can you add your html as well ?

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xpath` is invalid, or is a single `|`

```
wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@data-period='R6M'] | //span[@title='FYTD']"))).click();
```

You can also use `ExpectedConditions.or` fo this

```
wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@data-period='R6M']")),
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@title='FYTD']"))));
```

To get `WebElement` from one of two conditions you can build your own implementation

```
public ExpectedCondition<WebElement> customCondition(By... locators) {
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
        for (By locator in locators) {
            return ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator).apply(d);
        }
    }
}

WebElement element = wait4.until(customCondition(By.xpath("//a[@data-period='R6M']"), By.xpath("//span[@title='FYTD']")));
```

Comment: When i use the following, it asks to change webelement to boolean. While i would like to use as WebElement so that anyone of them can be clicked. Please suggest;   
    WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    WebElement element=wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@data-period='R6M']")),
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("//span[@title='FYTD']"))));

Comment: @ShaheryarKhawar `ExpectedConditions.or` return a boolean. You can use the first suggestion instead.

Comment: First suggestion uses only in case of xpath, but When i am searching for one className and other element as xpath in OR condition then?

Comment: @ShaheryarKhawar Update my answer. You can also always translate the `By.className` to xpath.

Answer (score 1):

To induce *WebDriverWait* for either one of the 2 elements using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [java](/questions/tagged/java) client you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@data-period='R6M']")),
    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@title='FYTD']"))
));
```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [How to wait for either of the two elements in the page using selenium xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166181/how-to-wait-for-either-of-the-two-elements-in-the-page-using-selenium-xpath/45170764#45170764)