# How to extract dynamic text from multiple child nodes within the html through getText()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

We have a Div containing some hard coded text and span containing some dynamic text values (refer below HTML code for more understanding). 
The resultant Text is: **1 Tasks to be updated from 'XYZ' to 'ABC'**

but when I am retrieving using Selenium locator i.e.

```
final String actual = $("#bulk_update_confirmation").text();
```

Then the actual contains only "Tasks to be updated from to". All the dynamic text are missing.

HTML code is as below (browser used is chrome)

```
<div id="bulk_update_confirmation" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 96.16px; height: auto;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
            <span id="taskCountSpan">1</span> Tasks to be updated from <span id="oldStatusSpan">'XYZ'</span> to <span id="newStatusSpan">'ABC'</span> <span id="desciptionSpan"> </span> <br>
            <hr>
            <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
                <button type="button" id="btn_bulk_update" onclick="updateBulkStatus()">Update</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="closeBulkUpdateRequest()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you attempt to extract the total text e.g. **1 Tasks to be updated from 'XYZ' to 'ABC'** you can induce *WebDriverWait* for all the three child *elements to be visible* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.and(
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@id='taskCountSpan']")),
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@id='oldStatusSpan']")),
    ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@id='newStatusSpan']"))
));
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works for me, Now i understand the problem, span is not populated hence text was missing. Waiting to populate the span does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Webelement.getText()` method to extract text and you can get the expected result as below

```
String actual =driver.findElement(By.id("bulk_update_confirmation")).getText();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update but the it is giving the same result. As per my understanding both the option are same either you use driver.findElement or $("#bulk_update_confirmation") locator will work in same way.