# How to wait for multiple conditions on invisibility_of_element_located using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, lambda, webdriverwait

I want to wait for the element to disappear on Selenium, but at the same time I must ensure that all the elements are gone. Right now, it is something like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))
)
is_clickable = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, layovers[0]))
)
is_clickable_2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, layovers[1]))
)

if is_clickable and is_clickable_2:
    element.click()
```

And there are more than two elements on the `layovers` list, which store xpaths as `str`.

In this case, can I make all of them into a single function that checks the invisibility of the elements, instead of repeating them? (I mean, make the *WebDriverWait* takes only one call, and not define another wrapper function.)

Answer (score 3):

### until_not()

The [`until_not(method, message='')`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait.until_not) method from [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait.until_not) class calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the return value is **False**.

---

### This usecase

As your usecase is to wait for multiple conditions on `invisibility_of_element_located()` through [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you can club up both the expected_conditions:

- `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, layovers[0])))`
- `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, layovers[1])))`

within a single expression using **`until_not()`** method through a **`lambda`**  expression as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until_not(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.XPATH,layovers[0]) and driver.find_element(By.XPATH,layovers[1]))
```

---

### Outro

You can find a couple of similar relevant discussions in:

- [Python / Selenium: Logic Operators in WebDriverWait Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147145/python-selenium-logic-operators-in-webdriverwait-expected-conditions/46147830#46147830)
- [How to extract dynamic text from multiple child nodes within the html through getText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034819/how-to-extract-dynamic-text-from-multiple-child-nodes-within-the-html-through-ge/51035034#51035034)

Answer (score 0):

First thing first :

the moment you write `WebDriverWait(driver, 30)`, an object of web driver wait (Explicit wait) will be created.

Instead you can do something like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
```

and you can use the reference variable `wait` as many times as you want in the same class.

You can create a method which will take **webdriverwait** reference and along with that you can pass **xpath** or locator as per your requirement.

```
def my_method(wait, xpath):
wait.until(
    expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, layovers[0]))
```

Hope this helps.