# selenium two xpath tests in one

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I try to combine check for two scenarios:

If startupcheck fails we get a try again button:

```
el = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "Try again")))
```

Or startupcheck succeed we get a pin enter request in a custom object:

```
el = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//Custom/Edit")))
```

How can this be combined into one check without having to check for both:
I tried the following:

```
check = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//Custom/Edit") or (By.NAME, "Try again")
))
```

But only the first `or` statement is checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can club up combine check for both the elements using `OR` clause through a lambda expression as follows:

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda x: (x.find_element_by_name("Try again"), x.find_element_by_xpath("//Custom/Edit")))
```

An alternative solution will be:

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.NAME,"Try again") and driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//Custom/Edit"))
```

---

As an alternative you can club up combine check for both the elements using the equivalent [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) as follows:

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='Try again'], Custom>Edit")))
```

---

### References

- [Python / Selenium: Logic Operators in WebDriverWait Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147145/python-selenium-logic-operators-in-webdriverwait-expected-conditions/46147830#46147830)
- [How to extract dynamic text from multiple child nodes within the html through getText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034819/how-to-extract-dynamic-text-from-multiple-child-nodes-within-the-html-through-ge/51035034#51035034)

Comment: Fantastic, I wish this was in the official documentation on https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Two questions:  I'm unfamiliar with the term "club up using OR clause".  what does that mean?  Also, in the "alternative example" code, why is there an "and" instead of an "or" between the conditions?

Comment: @rothloup Those are _lambda_ expressions to wait for expected conditions. For a simpler case see the discussion [Selenium's find_elements with two clauses for text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659942/seleniums-find-elements-with-two-clauses-for-text/65660325#65660325)

Comment: @DebanjanB:  I know that they are lambda expressions.  I don't understand what "club up"  means (sounds like a colloquialism, google searches for that don't turn up much), nor why an "OR" condition is checked with an "AND".