# Web-scraping (the class name changes)

Tags: python, selenium, lazy-loading, webdriverwait, classname

I am using selenium to download some images for my project!

For downloading images, I use the following command lines:

```
# Finding elements of images by class name
image_lm = prd.find_element_by_class_name('main')

# The URL to the image
image_url = image_lm.get_attribute('src')
```

Then, using image_url, I download the images.

The problem is that, after several tries, the class name changes to "main-lazy".

I can manually change the "main" to "main-lazy". is there any way to do it by code.

I am looking for a way to tell the code that either finds the class name of "main-lazy" is the class name of "main" is not available!

Comment: You could try getting the class "main" first. If it doesn't exist, then try "main-lazy".

Answer (score 1):

Why not `try/except` ?

```
try:
   image_lm = prd.find_element_by_class_name('main')
except Exception as e:
   print("changing to main_lazy \n"+e)
   image_lm = prd.find_element_by_class_name('main_lazy')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only two variations are "main" and "main-lazy" then you can try using:

```
By.XPath("//[contains(@class,'main')]
```

Sorry this is C# variation but I am sure you can figure out the Python equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css Or syntax of

```
image_lm = prd.find_element_by_css_selector('.main, .main-lazy')
```

Answer (score 1):

ClassName as **main-lazy** indicates the elements are loaded through [lazy-loading](/questions/tagged/lazy-loading). In such cases you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can club up combine check for both the elements using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) through a lambda expression as follows:

- Using `class_name` 1:

  ```
  image_lm = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda x: (x.find_element_by_class_name("main"), x.find_element_by_class_name("main-lazy")))
  ```
- Using `class_name` 2:

  ```
  image_lm = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"main") and driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"main-lazy"))
  ```

As an alternative you can club up combine check for both the elements using the equivalent [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) as follows:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  image_lm = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".main, .main-lazy")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [selenium two xpath tests in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890400/selenium-two-xpath-tests-in-one/57891188#57891188)