# Selenium's find_elements with two clauses for text?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

How can I use selenium's `find_elements_by_xpath()` based on text, when it may or may not have a word?

Example: it can be either `#1 here` or `#1 is here`. I want both to be part of the same list, since that func return a list. ATM I have `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '#1 here')]")` but that would only find the first case, not the ones with an `is`. Basically, something like `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '#1 here' or '#1 is here')]")`

How could I do that?

I'm also trying to keep their "order"
So, first one from top to bot is #1 on list, etc

I could do 2 different lists, one for each and then combine them but that would also screw that up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `or` clause you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Selenium3*:

  ```
  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(., 'this') or contains(., 'or this')]")
  ```
- *Selenium4*:

  ```
  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'this') or contains(., 'or this')]")
  ```

Comment: There is a typo in your xpaths. I suppose you meant `contains(., 'or this')` instead of `contains(,. 'or this')`, right?