# The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) in the type FluentWait is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, ExpectedCondition<WebElement>)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have been given two conditions based on which the webdriver needs to wait for either of the conditions to fulfill before moving ahead with execution. I am using Explicit wait along with `ExpectedConditions.or` for this purpose.

I tried using the below code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver.getDriver(),30).until(
    ExpectedConditions.or(
        ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return document.ReadyState")).equals("complete"),    
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(driver.findElement(By.Id("name"))
    )
);
```

I am getting the Error:

```
The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) in the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, ExpectedCondition<WebElement>)
```

Please note that I am using Guava 23.0 and its already added as a dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: What is `objMap`?

Comment: That was a call to our Object Map repository to fetch the Xpath

Answer (score 3):

`ExpectedConditions.or` receives `ExpectedCondition`s as parameters. When you compare the result of `ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue` to a string you are changing the all expression to `boolean`.

You can create custom `ExpectedCondition` to warp it

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Object> customeJsReturnsValue(final String javaScript) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ExpectedConditions.jsReturnsValue("return Spotfire.Busy.idle()")).equals("true")
        }
    }
}
```

Uses:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver.getDriver(),30).until(
    ExpectedConditions.or(
        customeJsReturnsValue("return document.ReadyState")).equals("complete"),
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(driver.findElement(By.Id("name"))
    )
);
```

Comment: I tried the above code.However, I am still getting the Error on the below line:
public static ExpectedCondition<Object> customeJsReturnsValue(final String javaScript) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Object>()
Error Message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from new ExpectedCondition<Object>(){} to String

Comment: Also, We have overriden ExpectedCondition method -> Would we have to override the ExpectedConditions.or method instead to return a boolean??

Answer (score 0):

### jsReturnsValue()

The *ExpectedConditions* of [`jsReturnsValue()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#jsReturnsValue-java.lang.String-) returns an *Object* and is defined as:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Object> jsReturnsValue(java.lang.String javaScript)

An expectation for String value from javascript

Parameters:
    javaScript - as executable js line

Returns:
    true once js return string
```

---

### visibilityOfElementLocated()

The *ExpectedConditions* of [`visibilityOfElementLocated()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) returns the *WebElement* and is defined as:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)

An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

Parameters:
locator - used to find the element

Returns:
the WebElement once it is located and visible
```

---

This error message...

```
The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) in the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (boolean, ExpectedCondition<WebElement>)
```

...implies that the `until()` is not appplicable for multiple return types `boolean` and `WebElement`.

In your usecase,

- `jsReturnsValue()` returns an *Object*.
- `visibilityOfElementLocated()` returns a *WebElement*.

---

### Solution

If you your *usecase* is about the visibility of a certain *WebElement* you can safely ignore the concern for **'document.readyState' equal to "complete"** as it would be an overhead. You can find a relevant discussion in [Selenium IE WebDriver only works while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709234/selenium-ie-webdriver-only-works-while-debugging/47710701#47710701).

However, to use the `until()` for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` for multiple element of similar type of data types you can follow the below example:

- Waiting for either of the elements among `By.xpath("//span[@id='id1']")` or `By.xpath("//span[@id='id2']")` be like:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.or(
      ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@id='id1']")),
      ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@id='id2']"))
  ));
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in

- [How to extract dynamic text from multiple child nodes within the html through getText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034819/how-to-extract-dynamic-text-from-multiple-child-nodes-within-the-html-through-ge/51035034#51035034)
- [How to wait for either of the two elements in the page using selenium xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166181/how-to-wait-for-either-of-the-two-elements-in-the-page-using-selenium-xpath/45170764#45170764)

---

### Outro

[Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-function-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleni/50329056#50329056)

Comment: `jsReturnsValue()` returns the value from the JavaScript query as `Object`, not `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the selenium dependency in the pom.xml and the error is gone.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
```