# Selenium webdriver - wait until 1 of 2 selectors is visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium to automatically download some reports based on a date that I input.

The page is updated by Javascript.

Sometimes the list of reports to download can take a while to load so I've used the WebDriverWait function.

There are several pages that can have no reports. This brings up a different css_selector to a page that has reports.

css_selector with no reports = "#report-list"

css_selector with reports = "#no_reports"

I've done a search online but the only solution I can find is for Java:
[Selenium Wait for anyone of Element to visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944097/selenium-wait-for-anyone-of-element-to-visible)

I've tried the code below but that doesn't work.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#reports-list","#no_reports")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait two elements in single css selector use:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#reports-list, #no_reports")))
```

In your code mistake is `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#reports-list","#no_reports")`.