# Change Seleniums default TimeoutException

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation, webdriver

In my test some of the elements which are located via a `css selector` take a long time to appear as the servers are very slow. I often get this error when running the tests through jenkins but not locally on eclipse.

```
> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
> waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector:
> #ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_uctlSettingUpPaymentCollectionGrid1_gvGroup_ctl02_deleteGroup
> (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Is it possible to increase this to more then 10 seconds on selenium?

Comment: You can refer this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944097/selenium-wait-for-anyone-of-element-to-visible/42944743). Here you can set the change the time from 10 to your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implicit waits - [docs here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait)

> There is a second type of wait that is distinct from explicit wait
> called implicit wait. By implicitly waiting, WebDriver polls the DOM
> for a certain duration when trying to find any element. This can be
> useful when certain elements on the webpage are not available
> immediately and need some time to load.

You set it once for your driver and it's a dynamic wait up until your specified timeout.

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Alternatively, you can use [explicit waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#options) per element that needs it:

```java
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(<<Your-Identifier>>));
```

With explicit waits you can ensure certain ExpectedConditions are ready and you control the timeout for the element to synchronise with.

A list of expected conditions for Java are [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

It is generally recommended you choose on approach if possible:

> Warning: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause
> unpredictable wait times. For example, setting an implicit wait of 10
> seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds could cause a timeout to
> occur after 20 seconds.